# Reset timeout on event with RxJS

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, frp, rxjs

I'm experimenting with RxJS (with the JQuery extension) and I'm trying to solve the following use case:

Given that I have two buttons (A & B) I'd like to print a message if a certain "secret combination" is clicked within a given timeframe. For example the "secret combination" could be to click "ABBABA" within 5 seconds. If the combination is not entered within 5 seconds a timeout message should be displayed. This is what I currently have:

```
var secretCombination = "ABBABA";

var buttonA = $("#button-a").clickAsObservable().map(function () { return "A"; });
var buttonB = $("#button-b").clickAsObservable().map(function () { return "B"; });

var bothButtons = Rx.Observable.merge(buttonA, buttonB);

var outputDiv = $("#output");

bothButtons.do(function (buttonName) {
    outputDiv.append(buttonName);
}).bufferWithTimeOrCount(5000, 6).map(function (combination) {
    return  combination.reduce(function (combination, buttonName) {
        return combination + buttonName;
    }, "");
}).map(function (combination) {
    return combination === secretCombination;
}).subscribe(function (successfulCombination) {
    if (successfulCombination) {
        outputDiv.html("Combination unlocked!");
    } else {
        outputDiv.html("You're not fast enough, try again!");
    }
});
```

While this works fairly well it's not exactly what I want. I need the `bufferWithTimeOrCount` to be reset when button A is pressed for the first time in a new timeframe. What I'm looking for is that as soon as the secret combination is pressed (ABBABA) I'd like "Combination unlocked!" to be shown (I don't want to wait for the time window to be expired).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Throttle](http://rxmarbles.com/#throttle) is the typical operator for the *delaying with reactive resetting* effect you want.

Here's how you can use throttle in combination with scan to gather the combination inputted before the 5 seconds of silence:

```
var evaluationStream = bothButtons
  .merge(bothButtons.throttle(5000).map(function(){return "reset";})) // (2) and (3)
  .scan(function(acc, x) { // (1)
    if (x === "reset") return "";
    var newAcc = acc + x;
    if (newAcc.length > secretCombination.length) {
      return newAcc.substr(newAcc.length - secretCombination.length);
    }
    else {
      return newAcc;
    }
  })
  .map(function(combination) {
    return combination === secretCombination;  
  });

var wrongStream = evaluationStream
  .throttle(5000)
  .filter(function(result) { return result === false; });

var correctStream = evaluationStream
  .filter(function(result) { return result === true; });

wrongStream.subscribe(function() {
  outputDiv.html("Too slow or wrong!");
});

correctStream.subscribe(function() {
  outputDiv.html("Combination unlocked!");
});
```

(1) We `scan` to concatenate the input characters. (2) Throttle waits for 5 seconds of event silence and emits the last event before that silence. In other words, it's similar to delay, except it resets the inner timer when a new event is seen on the source Observable. We need to reset the scan's concatenation (1), so we just map the same throttled Observable to "reset" flags (3), which the scan will interpret as clearing the accumulator (`acc`).

And here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/egybp1wk/15/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. It's a good improvement but it's not exactly what I'm looking for (perhaps the question is a bit unclear, I will edit the question). If you go to the JSFiddle page and click "BBABBABA" you get "Too slow or wrong!". I want this to be correct since you have indeed clicked ABBABA (I don't care that BB was clicked prior to ABBABA). Also I would like "Combination unlocked!" to be displayed instantly after having pressed ABBABA. I don't want to wait until the time window has expired.

Comment: So why do you need the "5 seconds"? Why not just concatenate the characters in the scan, and take the last 6 characters to be compared in the following map?

Comment: Because I still want the secret combination to be entered within 5 seconds once its initiated. Let's say that I've pressed "BB" and now I press "A". I now have 5 seconds to press the remaining "BBABA". If a timeout or wrong input occur I have to restart.

Comment: In that case you need to split the Observable into two because you want the throttle behavior on only one side. See the updated answer. And the updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/egybp1wk/15/

Comment: The jsfiddle jsfiddle.net/egybp1wk/15 will accept the correct entry as long as each character is entered within 5 seconds, not within five seconds total.

Comment: @bnieland this discussion evolved over at Github, and there we got correct solutions: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/issues/276