# Recognizing and exact series of events in RxJS

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs

Using RxJS, I want to fire an event if the user types 'a' then 'b' then 'c'.

I do not want the event fired if they enter 'a' then 'b' then 'z' then 'c'.

Here is my [codepen](http://codepen.io/brettnieland/pen/zrPXxe) of the work I have done so far (in TypeScript).

```
class App1 {
    private divStream: HTMLElement;
    private divResult: HTMLElement;

    constructor(divStream: HTMLElement, divResult: HTMLElement) {
            this.divStream = divStream;
            this.divResult = divResult;
    }

    start() {
        var filterByCharacter = (expectedCharater) => {
            return (char) => { return char === expectedCharater; };
        };

        var values = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'b'];

        var obChars = Rx.Observable.fromArray(values);
        obChars.subscribe((k) => {
            divStream.innerHTML += "<div style='color: blue'>" + ":: " + k + " ::" + "</div>";
                },
            (err) => {
                divStream.innerHTML += "<div style='background-color: blue' > " + 'Error: ' + err + " </div>";
            },
            () => {
                divStream.innerHTML += "<div style='background-color: blue'>" + ":: finished ::" + "</div>";
            }
        );

        function log(text: string) {
            divResult.innerHTML += "<div style='color: green'>" + text + "</div>";
        }
        var obA: Rx.Observable<string> = obChars.filter(filterByCharacter('a'));
        var obB: Rx.Observable<string> = obChars.filter(filterByCharacter('b'));
        var obC: Rx.Observable<string> = obChars.filter(filterByCharacter('c'));

        let aSteps: Rx.Observable<any>[] = [];
        aSteps.push(obA.take(1).do(() => { log("a"); }).ignoreElements());
        aSteps.push(obB.take(1).do(() => { log("b"); }).ignoreElements());
        aSteps.push(obC.take(1).do(() => { log("c"); }));
        let steps: Rx.Observable<any> = Rx.Observable.concat<any>(aSteps);
        var source = steps
            .takeUntil(Rx.Observable.timer(100 * values.length));

              var subscription = source.subscribe(
            function (x) {
                log("Next: " + x);
            },
            function (err) {
                divResult.innerHTML += "<div style='background-color: green'>Error: " + err + "</div>";
            },
            function () {
                divResult.innerHTML += "<div style='background-color: green' > " + 'Completed' + "</div>";
            });
    }

    stop() {
        clearTimeout(this.timerToken);
    }

}

window.onload = () => {
    var app = new App1(document.getElementById('divStream'), document.getElementById('divResult'));
    app.start();
};
```

Comment: FYI: I saw a "reduce" method of achieving this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25833495/reset-timeout-on-event-with-rxjs?rq=1.  I am looking for something a little more RxJS native.

Comment: Another comment: when I say I'm looking for something more RxJS native, I mean that I'm looking for a declarative answer, not an imperative one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be working, it uses a [simple state machine](http://jsfiddle.net/s0j5g3v5/1/) and is generalizable to recognize any basic regular expression. The regular expression recognized here is *abc* :

```
function noop () {}

var keyUp$ = 
  Rx.Observable.fromEvent(ta_input, 'keyup')
               .map(function(ev){return ev.keyCode});

var stateMachine$ = keyUp$
  .scan(function (state, keyCode) {
    if (String.fromCharCode(keyCode) === state.password[state.index]) {
      state.index++;
      if (state.index === state.password.length) {
        state.found = true;
      }
    } 
    else {
      state.index = 0;
      state.found = false;
    }
    return state;
}, {password : 'ABC', index : 0, found: false})
  .filter(function (state){return state.found})
  .take(1)

stateMachine$.subscribe(noop)
```

To check it, run the jsffidle, and type *abc* in the textarea. For some reason, your password has to be in caps, but that part should be easy to fix. When the `abc` substring is detected, the `stateMachine$` observable emits `found` and completes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. While this is a valid solution, the spirit of our RxJS is not to use state or imperative techniques, at least that's how I interpret it.

Comment: What do you mean by state or imperative techniques here?? This seems to me as standard and 'native' (what the does that even mean) RxJS as it can be. RxJS builds up streams through sources combined through operators and subscribed to by observers. Operators often take selector functions. Those functions are imperative procedural code and there is no way around it, or stop coding in javascript. What is preferrable is a style in which the output streams only depends on the input streams and input data. This is the same as using pure functions vs. functions performing side effects.

Comment: So with RxJS it is recommended to avoid side effects or to localize them for example in the `do` operator. There is no side effect in this code, it is purely functional in the sense that the output stream is a pure function of the input streams. i.e. at two different times you pass a given click data flow to that function, it will output the exact same thing. Replace  `stateMachine` by `deterministicFiniteAutomaton` or `exactStringMatcher`, and replace `state` with `step`. It might help you see that there is no state here, just standard data flow, and no side-effects.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, and, of course, you are correct about my "state" argument.  As for my objection to using imperative techniques, I hoped for, perhaps naively, a solution that looked more like `keyUp.assertNext(function(v) { return v == 'a';}).assertNext(function(v) { return v == 'b';})..assertNext(function(v) { return v == 'c';});`.  where `assertNext` is a notional operator of mine that 'takes' an event on true, and throws an error on false. If nothing more aligned with this comes up, I will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: I forked your jsFiddle, making a few mods to allow for "aabc" to complete successfully.  http://jsfiddle.net/h0fab5z0/

Comment: yes sorry for the mistake. I wrote it a bit quick so I overlooked the small details. And I still don't know why you have to use caps but anyways. The idea is that one. `scan` is an horizontal combinator, i.e. you can do x_n+1 = f(x_n,y_n) computations, which allows to implement with it any finite automata. I am curious about `assertNext` though. It seems to take an event (x_n) and pass-on an event downstream or error. But the event passed is the next one (x_n+1), so this is also an horizontal combinator so it can probably be realized also with `scan`. Your code looks more readable I agree.

Comment: The caps are do to ev.keycode always returning caps, as it is a key code, not a character code.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for [bufferWithCount](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/bufferwithcount.md).

Check out this [spec](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/blob/master/spec/operators/bufferCount-spec.js#L39-L46) from RxJSNext (renamed bufferCount in next):

```
it('should emit full buffer then last partial buffer if source completes', function () {
  var e1 =   hot('--a^-b--c--d--e--|');
  var e1subs =      '^             !';
  var expected =    '--------y-----(z|)';

  expectObservable(e1.bufferCount(3)).toBe(expected, {
                                             y: ['b', 'c', 'd'],
                                             z: ['e']
                                           });
  expectSubscriptions(e1.subscriptions).toBe(e1subs);
 });
```